# SQLyog and MariaDB engine

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, storage-engine, xtradb

I am quite new in MariaDB and I use SQLyog Community Edition as the frontend GUI. Whenever I create a new table, on the **Engine** dropdown, there is no XtraDB option. Is there any additional steps I am missing? As I've read, XtraDB is the InnoDB improved. How can I set my table to have that engine?

[image]

Here is my `SHOW ENGINES` result:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW ENGINES;

    +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
    +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables                  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears)             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | MRG_MyISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                                     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | FEDERATED          | YES     | FederatedX pluggable storage engine                                        | YES          | NO   | YES        |
    | InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Percona-XtraDB, Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
    | Aria               | YES     | Crash-safe tables with MyISAM heritage                                     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: I need a favor. Please login to MariaDB and run `SHOW ENGINES`. In the row that has `InnoDB`, look at the comment section. What does it say ???

Comment: I have edited my post for your question, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, XtraDB is used as the InnoDB replacement.

If you login to MariaDB and run [`SHOW ENGINES;`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-engines/), look for the `InnoDB`.

According to the Documentation for [`SHOW ENGINES;`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-engines/):

> Note that both MySQL's InnoDB and Percona's XtraDB replacement are labeled as InnoDB. However, if XtraDB is in use, it will be specified in the COMMENT field. See XtraDB and InnoDB. The same applies to FederatedX.

Based on your [`SHOW ENGINES;`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-engines/) output, you are using XtraDB now.

In case you need to revert back to the original InnoDB, see [Using InnoDB Instead of XtraDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/using-innodb-instead-of-xtradb/). It discusses flipping the plugins and restart MariaDB.

As for XtraDB, you can read the [Documentation](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server/xtradb).

I can tell you one thing that I wish MySQL's InnoDB had: MORE INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Check out the [5.5](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/index_info_schema_tables.html) and [5.6](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/index_info_schema_tables.html) INFORMATION_SCHEMA extensions for Percona and [see how they compare to those in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/information-schema-innodb-tables/).

To see which parts of XtraDB can be tuned and monitored (which InnoDB cannot do), look at this [Pictorial Representation of InnoDB (originated by Vadim Tkachenko)](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing).

Comment: That was quick man, thanks. Additionally, mind if you give me some quick insights of benefits of XtraDB to InnoDB?

Comment: More [information](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradb-and-innodb/) than you could ever want or need on that topic :-)